# Get publish artifact in CI for Class Library like Web app (WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf, tfs, continuous-integration, artifact

I'm trying to build Ci for C# project. My solution contains a class library project which implemented WCF services itself.

When I get manual to publish for this project it works fine, But in CI process I can't get the artifact from this project because build task does not recognize it as WCF Service.

I changed project type from class library to WCF but in this case by WCF service files does not appear in published files.

Any suggestions will be appreciated Thanks in advance.

MSBuild parameters:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Manual publish:

[image]

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: could you get me any help? thanks a lot.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/7409220/shayki-abramczyk